# Difference in pasting content into CM RTF fields between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-manager, rtf, browser

When copy-pasting content with line breaks into RTF fields in the Content Manager (2013 SP1 HR1) in Firefox and Chrome I see different HTML generated in the source tab. Is anyone aware of a fix for this other than manually editing the source?

Here's the source in Firefox...

[image]

and in Chrome

[image]

This is the test text for anyone wanting to test this out

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Vestibulum dui sapien, egestas id odio a.
sollicitudin vestibulum nisi.

Morbi ut sapien ut arcu viverra accumsan tincidunt vel neque.
```

Comment: In SDL Tridion 2011 the browsers handled returns differently, but there was an update to the default rich text format area XSLT filter. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/29505/15311 for the behavior. Does changing tabs or saving change the markup? Do you see the same for new Schemas (I believe older Schemas keep their original XSLT filters)?

Comment: I tried the above in Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 with Google Chrome 45.0.2 and got the something similar to the below.  

<pre class="default prettyprint prettyprinted" style="margin-top: 0px; padding: 5px;>
<code style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, 'Lucida Console', 'Liberation Mono', 'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', monospace, sans-serif; white-space: inherit;"><span class="typ" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(43, 145, 175);">Lorem</span>

Comment: It`s sdl tridion product issue. please create sdl support for this RTF copy and Paste Issue.

Answer (score 1):

We implemented the ValidateRtfCopyPasteCommand Extension to resolve this issue. Please find sample code below:

```
     Tridion.Type.registerNamespace("SDLPS.Extensions");

        SDLPS.Extensions.ValidateRtfInputCommand = function ValidateRtfInputCommand() {
            Tridion.OO.enableInterface(this, "SDLPS.Extensions.ValidateRtfInputCommand");
            this.addInterface("Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.Base.Commands.CommandBase", ["ValidateRtfInputCommand"]);};

        SDLPS.Extensions.ValidateRtfInputCommand.prototype._isAvailable = function ValidateRtfInputCommand$_isAvailable(selection, pipeline) {  
            return true;
        };

        SDLPS.Extensions.ValidateRtfInputCommand.prototype._isEnabled = function ValidateRtfInputCommand$_isEnabled(selection, pipeline) {    
            return true;
        };

    // Global variables exposed to all
    var currentData_cpc = {};
    var pasteEventFired_cpc = false;
    var activateExtension_cpc = false;
    $vri = SDLPS.Extensions.ValidateRtfInputCommand;
    $vri.range, $vri.cursorLocation;
    $vri.markerId = "PasteParent";


    // the pasted entry will be stripped of <br> tags if set to false the pasted content will be left as is.
    $vri.removeBrExisting = true;


    if ($display && activateExtension_cpc) {
        $evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStarted_cpc);
    }


    function onDisplayStarted_cpc() {  
        $evt.removeEventHandler($display, "start", onDisplayStarted_cpc);
        var view = $display.getView();
        if (view && Tridion.OO.implementsInterface(view, "Tridion.Cme.Views.Component")) {
            var fieldBuilder = view.properties.controls.fieldBuilder;
            $evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "load", _applyLoadEvent_cpc);      
            $evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "change", _applyLoadEvent_cpc);      
            $evt.addEventHandler(fieldBuilder, "insert", _applyLoadEvent_cpc);  
        }
    }

function evtPaste_cpc(event) {

    var entryKey = this.entrykey;
    var curCtrl = $j("iframe.FAIFrame[id='" + entryKey + "']");
    var selection = curCtrl.focus()[0].contentWindow.getSelection();

    $vri.range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    $vri.caretStartContainer = $vri.range.startContainer;
    if ($vri.caretStartContainer.firstChild) {
        $vri.caretStartContainer.firstChild.id = "endPaste";
        $vri.endPasteSet = true;

    }
    else if ($vri.caretStartContainer.nextSibling) {
        $vri.caretStartContainer.nextSibling.id = "endPaste";
        $vri.endPasteSet = true;

    } else {

        $vri.endPasteSet = false;
    }
    $vri.caretEndContainer = $vri.range.endContainer;
    $vri.caretContainerNodeType = $vri.caretStartContainer.nodeType;
    $vri.pasteNodeText = $vri.range.startContainer.data;
    $vri.caretStartOffset = $vri.range.startOffset;

    pasteEventFired_cpc = true;
};
function finalizeRtfInput_cpc(entryKey) {

    console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: finalizeRtfInput_cpc called on save or save and close");

    var currentInput = $j("iframe.FAIFrame[id='" + entryKey + "']");

    if (!currentInput) {
        console.error("ValidateRtfInput: was unable to locate the RTF Field with id -> " + entryKey);
        return;
    }
    var currentVal;
    try {
        currentVal = currentInput[0].contentDocument.activeElement.innerHTML;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("ValidateRtfInput: Unable to access the innerHTML of the RTF Filed with id -> " + entryKey);
        console.error("ValidateRtfInput Error Message: " + err.message);
        return;
    }

    var lastVal = currentData_cpc[entryKey];
    var dmp = new diff_match_patch();
    dmp.Patch_Margin = 10;
    console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: \n-------------\nLastEntry:\n" + lastVal + "\n-------------\n\nCurrentEntry:\n" + currentVal + "\n-------------\n");

    var arDiff = dmp.diff_main(lastVal, currentVal, false);

    if (arDiff.length >= 2) {
        for (index = 0; index < arDiff.length; index++) {
            // check each diff
            if (arDiff[index][0] == 1) {
                var valToCheck = arDiff[index][1];
                var newVal = valToCheck.replace(/ <br>/, ' ');
                newVal = newVal.replace(/ <\/p>/, '<\/p>');
                newVal = newVal.replace(/ <br><\/p>/, '<\/p>');
                console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: Checked val[" + index + "][1]: " + valToCheck);
                console.debug("ValidateRtfInput:  --- newVal: " + newVal);
                arDiff[index][1] = newVal;
                if (newVal == " ") console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: Final matches found a space all alone to be added. Maybe need to look ahead and see if the next change contains <br or other html");

            }
        }
    }
    else {
        console.debug("ValidateRtfInput extension expected a diff >= 2 and got " + arDiff.length + " It is likely there were no changes in this RTF Field");
    }
    var patchMade = dmp.patch_make(arDiff);


    var cleanedTxt = dmp.patch_apply(patchMade, lastVal);
    console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: patch_apply results: " + cleanedTxt[0]);

    var nextUpdate = cleanedTxt[0];
    if (nextUpdate.match(/ <br>/g)) {
        console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: Update data contains ' <br>' stripping now");
        nextUpdate = nextUpdate.replace(/ <br>/, ' ');
        console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: ------------\nNew save value: \n" + nextUpdate + "\n------------");
    }


    currentData_cpc[entryKey] = nextUpdate;

    currentInput[0].contentDocument.activeElement.innerHTML = nextUpdate;

    if (lastVal == currentVal) {
        console.debug("ValidateRtfInput: previous and current values have not changed for: " + entryKey);
    }

};
```